# php-form-builder-class not rendering

Tags: php

I'm trying to use [PFBC](http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/) and am having some problems.

On one server the folder "PFBC" has been uploaded to /public_html/ and the form is rendering fine.

On the non-working server the folder "PFBC" has been uploaded to /www/htdocs/ and the form is not rendering at all and I'm getting Error 500 Internal Server Errors.

The code I am using is as follows

```
<?php
session_start();
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/PFBC/Form.php");
$form = new PFBC\Form("TestForm", 300);
$form->addElement(new PFBC\Element\Button);
$form->render();
?>
```

`echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/PFBC/Form.php";`

returns `/usr/home/thin30/www/htdocs/PFBC/Form.php`

and adding the following code to the Form.php file

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "<p>Full path to this dir: " . $dir . "</p>";
```

returns `Full path to this dir: /usr/home/thin30/www/htdocs/PFBC`

Can someone please tell me why the form isn't rendering? Or point me in a direction that may be helpful?

Folder permissions on `/PFBC/` are `755` (both working server & non-working server).

Comment: Are you sure your version of php is >= 5.3?

Comment: No; it's 5.2.17. In what way does this make a difference? Sorry, I'm not very good with PHP.

Comment: Yes it does. That code seems to be using name spaces which requires php 5.3 or greater.

Comment: Okay, so if I used an older version of PFBC that doesn't use name spaces it might be better/work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No; it's 5.2.17. In what way does this make a difference? Sorry, I'm good with PHP.

Yes it does. That code seems to be using name spaces which requires php 5.3 or greater.

ACtually upon looking at the google code page it looks like you can use the 2.x version without using the namespaces the example they give is:

```
/PFBC 2.x PHP 5
session_start();
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/PFBC/Form.php");
$form = new Form("GettingStarted", 300);
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("My Textbox:", "MyTextbox"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Select("My Select:", "MySelect", array(
   "Option #1",
   "Option #2",
   "Option #3"
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Button);
$form->render();
```

Comment: This still gives me errors. Perhaps I should try to find an older version of PFBC then.

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct/separate downloads for this project - one for PHP 5 (no namespaces) and another for PHP 5.3+.  You have to use namespaces in the PHP 5.3+ version, and you can't use them in the PHP 5 version.

To solve your issue, you'll want to download the PHP 5 version (http://php-form-builder-class.googlecode.com/files/pfbc2.3-php5.zip) and replace your server's existing PFBC directory with the one included in the download.

Hope this helps.